# How to create text file from LINQ merged list?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, join

I've got 2 LINQ-to-SQL lists and I merge them into 1 list using:

```
var mergedList = List1.Union(List2);
```

I assume that the Union command will eliminate all dupes in the list.  Is that right?  Anyway, I'm trying to write the contents of the merged list into a csv file.  I'm getting errors when I try to call the list in:

```
WriteToCSVFile cf = new WriteToCSVFile(mergedList);
```

and this is how I constructed my class:

```
public WriteToCSVFile(IEnumerable<T> mergedList)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Btw, this are the errors I'm getting:

```
The type arguments for method 'WriteToCSVFile.WriteToCSVFile(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If you need more info, please let me know.  And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your class generic

```
public class WriteToCSVFile<T>
{
    public WriteToCSVFile(IEnumerable<T> mergedList)
    {

    }

    ...
}
```

and when calling it specify the generic argument type because generic types cannot be inferred from constructors:

```
var cf = new WriteToCSVFile<TheTypeOfElementsInYourList>(mergedList);
```

Type inference works only with methods, so you could write an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class CsvExtensions
{
    public static void WriteToCSVFile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then:

```
mergedList.WriteToCSVFile();
```

Oh, and I sincerely hope that you are [not rolling your own CSV parser](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp), do you?

Comment: This might be a question for a different thread.  After merging 2 LINQ lists, how can I preserve the table objects?  I thought that it would but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @inquisitive_one, indeed this deserves a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous types can't be used as type parameter for generic methods.

Comment: Define result class explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

As your method is generic method, I guess you are passing non generic list. I guess your list types are defined as

```
List list1= new List();
```

It should be defined as

```
List<yourType> list1 = new List<yourType>();
```

Comment: Yes, you're right.  This is what I'm using to create my LINQ list:  'var List1 = from uscomp in USdb.UScompanies
                          join ussect in USdb.USsectors
                          on uscomp.sector_code equals ussect.sector_code
                          select new
                          {                              
                              uscomp.company_name,
                              uscomp.ticker,
                              ussect.description
                          }'